# good design for defining relationship between address and properties

Tags: sql, relational-database, relationship

I really want to give some thought to this situation, I want to map addresses and properties. The address table is filled based on the information retrieved from google maps and inserted on the table. Repetition is present on the table, if a two different people register two properties on the same address (neighbors) (no property number is inserted) the address table  will have two identical address with two different ids. I have two design ideas and both will work fine, no doubt about it but both seem weird somehow.

My first design, I will have each property table have and address_id.
Why it is weird for me, "it seems that the address table owns a property (the foreign key in the "main entity") when it is the opposite the property owns an address.

[image]

My second design, the address table will have two column to find the correct "property".
The property type and property id.

[image]

which design should I use. There's some other better option?

I simplified things a little, but the idea is 100% here.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL.

Comment: "seem weird somehow" is not helpful. What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re how/why you are 1st stuck on what step among which steps following what published presentation of what design method/process given what? [ask] [Help] 'better" doesn't mean anything in particular. Then once you define it, how are you stuck deciding? [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)

Answer (score 0):

The first design is, for most generic requirements, the standard implementation. A property has an attribute of an address